# How to get the thread/class name that caused memory leak?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, websphere, heap-memory

I have heap dump from production server which was facing OutOfMemory exception. I have core dumps of multiple threads. I can load heap dump to IBM HeapAnalyzer, I see that there is 2.5GB of Strings. Ok I have addresses of those Strings. However, how can I find out which class/thread caused the memory leak? This was very rare error, so please, no VisualVM available, nor connecting to the app. I have just heap dump (.PHD), javacore dumps (.TXT) and application logs.

[image]

Comment: Can you show relevant sections of your heap-dump?

Comment: Can you specify which sections? I attached screenshot from HA.

Comment: Usually in these tools (I use Eclipse Memory Analyser, not yours) you can go "up" the references to see what objects reference these string. Go up till your reach objects in your classes.

Comment: Yeah that would be perfect, but I have java/lang/Object as one of the root nodes. Could it be caused by the JVM itself?